# enable auto recompilation in grails vaadin project

Tags: grails, internationalization, vaadin, dynamic-compilation

I have a grails vaadin project. the auto recompilation feature used to work well until I began to use internationalization, since then I have to restart the server to recompile any change.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the watched resources section in VaadinGrailsPlugin.groovy (within the plugin) it's very clear that changes to the messages.properties files are not causing the plugin to reconfigure the way it dynamically handles i8n messages.

Put simply the plugin (v 1.4) doesn't support reloading it's i8n methods when you change messages.properties.

Comment: in my VaadinGrailsPlugin.groovy I have
def watchedResources = ["file:./grails-app/vaadin/**/*.groovy"]
But any change I made to any groovy class in this folder is ignored by the recompiler.

Comment: I have never used the Vaadin (or the plugin for Grails), but reading the source for the plugin and the onChange closure it looks like it /should/ be reloading the class you changed. You may want to raise a JIRA issue regarding this. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPVAADIN